# How can one show that $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ is surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How can one show that $f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$ is surjective, where $f:\mathbb R \to (-1,1)$?

I showed that it's injective but I'm still stuck at
$$
F(x)=y\Rightarrow \frac{x}{1+|x|}=y\Rightarrow y+y|x|=x
$$
How can one find the inverse?

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of the function?

Comment: X in ]-1;1[  but f is surj from R to -1;1

Comment: You could look at the maxima and minima and use intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Can you give hint

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|} \implies 
 f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  \frac{x}{1+x} & \text{if}\ x>0 \\
  \frac{x}{1-x} & \text{if}\ x\leq0
\end{cases}$$

So,

$$
\begin{cases}
  (f(x)-1)(x+1)=-1  & \text{if}\ x>0 \\
  (f(x)+1)(x-1)=-1 & \text{if}\ x\leq0
\end{cases}
$$

So, the graph is as follows-[image]

As it has been pointed out in Byung's answer that surjectivity of the function will depends upon the definition of your co-domain, because here your range is $(-1,1)$.

So the function is surjective if your co-domain is $(-1,1)$, but if it is given as some bigger set then the function will not be surjective.

If we assume the co-domain is $(-1,1)$ then inverse of the function will be-

$$
\begin{cases}
  (x-1)(f^{-1}(x)+1)=-1  & \text{if}\ x>0 \\
  (x+1)(f^{-1}(x)-1)=-1 & \text{if}\ x\leq0
\end{cases}
$$

$$ \implies 
 f^{-1}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{1-x}-1 & \text{if}\ x>0 \\
  \frac{-1}{1+x}+1 & \text{if}\ x\leq0
\end{cases}$$

$$ \implies 
 f^{-1}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
  \frac{x}{1-x} & \text{if}\ x>0 \\
  \frac{x}{1+x} & \text{if}\ x\leq0
\end{cases}$$

$$ \implies 
 f^{-1}(x) = \frac{x}{1-|x|} \text{ where } f^{-1}:(-1,1) \rightarrow (-\infty, \infty)$$

Comment: So what is the inverse of the function

Comment: Check out the edited answer to find out the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Important fact: ${\rm sgn}(f(x)) = {\rm sgn}(x)$.

For the case $y\in(-1,1)$, $y\ge 0$:

As ${\rm sgn}(f(x))\ge 0$, we want $x\ge 0$ and $|x| = x$. So,
$$y = f(x) = \frac{x}{1+|x|} = \frac{x}{1+x},$$
i.e.,
$$y + yx = (1+x)y = x,$$
and $x=\cdots$ Can you continue?

Comment: @user233658, is a first degree equation in $x$.

Comment: @user233658, $x(y-1) = -y$, $x=\cdots$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of surjective is a function whose image is equal to the codomain. I assume that the function $f$ in your question is $f : \mathbb{R} \to (-1,1)$, in which case you want to show $f(\mathbb{R}) = (-1,1)$. That is, there is no point in the codomain ($(-1,1)$) that is not mapped to by $f$.

In practice, you want to show that for every point $y \in (-1,1)$, there is a point $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. It will be sufficient to just find some value of $x$ (perhaps in terms of $y$) that will give you $f(x) = y$. I hope this is enough to get you started on your solution.

Comment: Im stuck there in solving the equation

Comment: How far have you managed to get? You should have been clearer in your original question.